# LWC projects related

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, html

I am trying to practice LWC,  Is there any place, channel, blog where I can find LWC Projects for practice?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Haven't you checked Trailhead? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/build-lightning-web-components

Answer (score 0):

@Bahtiyar Polat,

Refer to this LWC component and practice projects to understand the concepts of the LWC.

- https://www.awesomelwc.com/
- https://salesforcediaries.com/category/lightning-web-component/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy!!!